# Minify CSS / JS files and create one file using a command line

Tags: javascript, css, minify

I have many CSS & JS files. Ideally, I just want to use some command line tool to select all those css & js files, and minify them into one file each. Any simple tools for this?

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Linux, sorry I didn't mention that

Comment: Surely you can just copy and paste all the JS files yourself? And then copy and paste all the css into that one file as well?

Comment: Have a look at yui compressor or google closure compiler. Both are excellent for these kind of tasks.

Comment: @minseong And I also need it modified, sorry, don't want to do it manually

Comment: idk about mixing your _CSS_ and _JavaScript_, but I'm pretty sure you should be able to stick them together in a binary way - `cat a.js b.js c.js > complete.js` or `cat *.js > complete.js` (won't guarantee order). This question probably belongs on superuser

Comment: @PaulS. I need it also minified (and I don't want to mix them both, I want 2 files (one for css, one for js))

Comment: @good_evening pass it through a minifier after merging them all

Answer (score 8):

The npm respository offers many command line tools for this, for example:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifycss

Just install them with "npm install -g [package-name]", after installing [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) - which comes with npm.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [yuicompressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)? It minifies and combines multiple CSS files (or JS files) and concatenates them to one single file.

Example:

```
yuicompressor *.js > javascript.min.js
```

Comment: I have long been using yuicompressor, but recently found out, that css values with "calc()" sometimes are destroyed by falsely deleting whitespace. Example: `calc(225px+40em)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use gulp to do this.

Take a look at this tutorial for some simple examples, including css and js minification :
http://julienrenaux.fr/2014/05/25/introduction-to-gulp-js-with-practical-examples/
Of note is the js example, which demonstrates minifiying an entire directory - you can do the same with css as well.

You will have to create one small config file unless you use the gulp-shell node package. I probably wouldn't bother with that when first learning gulp.

There are a few "set up gulp" tutorials, including this one: http://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp.

A build tool like gulp or grunt are made to do this, plus you can do a lot more once you're familiar with one of them.